# CSS Icon Rotation Second Animation On Mouseoff

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a jfiddle for a rotating icon that gets larger when it rotates on mouseover: https://jsfiddle.net/clotoro/29cj137x/73/

```
<div class="rotate-wrapper">
 <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
   <span class="resize-hover">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
   </span>
 </span>
</div>

.rotate-wrapper:hover .fa-stack {
color: #dd4814;
transition: 1.6s;
transform: rotateY(360deg);
font-size: 6em;
}

.wrapper {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

.rotate-wrapper:hover .fa-stack {
color: #dd4814;
transition: 1.6s;
transform: rotateY(360deg);
font-size: 6em;
}

.wrapper {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

.resize-hover {
font-size: 140%
}
```

Instead of it just snapping back to size, I want to have the rotation animation play once again when mouseover ends, and have it shrink back to its original size.

Any ideas? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `transition` on the element, not the `:hover` state, and set an initial `transform` value for the element to transition back to after mouse out:

```css
.rotate-wrapper .fa-stack {
  transition: 1.6s;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.rotate-wrapper:hover .fa-stack {
  color: #dd4814;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  font-size: 6em;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.resize-hover {
  font-size: 140%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="rotate-wrapper">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <span class="resize-hover">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Turnip, that's perfect!